# How to get working Flip counter plugin in Blazor Server App

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to implemenet the [FLIP counter plugin](https://github.com/pqina/flip/) (JS + CSS) in Blazor Server App.

By Flip's manual I have added

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@pqina/flip/dist/flip.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@pqina/flip/dist/flip.min.js"></script>
```

into the `<head>` of  `_Layout` file.

The `html` I put into `Index` page

```
<div class="tick"
     data-value="1234"
     data-did-init="setupFlip">
  
    <!-- Hide visual content from screenreaders with `aria-hidden` -->
    <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
        <span data-view="flip"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the `JS` code into the `Layout` just to see how it works

```
<script>
function setupFlip(tick) { 
    Tick.helper.interval(function() { 
        tick.value++; 
        // Set `aria-label` attribute which screenreaders will read instead of HTML content
        tick.root.setAttribute('aria-label', tick.value);
        console.log(tick.value);
    }, 1000); 
}
</script>
```

Finally when I start app I see that **Flip counter executes once and UI does not updates anymore**. But the `console.log(tick.value);` is still working.

As I see it has something to do with [ASP.NET Core Blazor JavaScript interoperability (JS interop)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) but not sure how to exactly.

I assume that somehow I have to use `StateHasChanged()` to command Blazor Server App to update UI but   I cannot figure out how to do it.

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using `JS interop`. After the HTML is rendered, blazor needs to call the javascript (using interop) so that it can keep track of the DOM changes. I went to the [product website](https://pqina.nl/tick/), to see exactly how to setup the `tick` object. It is created by calling `Tick.DOM.create`, and passing in the already rendered `tick` element. Use this script :

```
<script>
   function setupFlip(tick) { 
        Tick.helper.interval(function() { 
            tick.value++; 
            // Set `aria-label` attribute which screenreaders will read instead of HTML content
            tick.root.setAttribute('aria-label', tick.value);
            console.log(tick.value);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function getTickAndSetup() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tick');
        var element = elements[0];
        var tick = Tick.DOM.create(element);
        setupFlip(tick);
    }
</script>
```

For the HTML, remove the attribute `data-did-init`, so that you can control when to start the tick.

```
<div class="tick"
     data-value="1234">

    <!-- Hide visual content from screenreaders with `aria-hidden` -->
    <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
        <span data-view="flip"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I started the flip module using a button in blazor. You could probably put it in a `OnInitializedAsync()` or `OnAfterRenderAsync`. (use the `firstRender` parameter to only render it once).

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="tick"
     data-value="1234">

    <!-- Hide visual content from screenreaders with `aria-hidden` -->
    <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
        <span data-view="flip"></span>
    </div>
</div>


<br />
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CallSetup">Call setup</button>


@code {
    private async Task CallSetup()
    {        
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("getTickAndSetup");
    }
}
```

The article you linked just mentioned concepts about JS interop. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is documentation on how to implement it (by injecting `IJSRuntime`).

Answer (score 1):

Issue is likely due to Blazor's rendering lifecycle. FLIP relies on JS to manipulate DOM,it might conflict with rendering process. JS interop is probably the solution that will work:

Move your JS to separate file, `flipInterop.js` for example, in your `wwwroot/js` folder:

```
// flipInterop.js
window.flipInterop = {
    setupFlip: function (elementId) {
        const tick = Tick.DOM.create(document.getElementById(elementId), {});

        Tick.helper.interval(function () {
            tick.value++;
            tick.root.setAttribute('aria-label', tick.value);
            console.log(tick.value);
        }, 1000);

        return true;
    }
};
```

In `_Layout.cshtml` add reference to it:

```
<script src="~/js/flipInterop.js"></script>
```

in your `Index.razor` use `@ref` to reference the `div` and call the JS interop method:

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div id="flipCounter" class="tick" data-value="1234">
    <div data-repeat="true" aria-hidden="true">
        <span data-view="flip"></span>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private ElementReference _counterDiv;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("flipInterop.setupFlip", _counterDiv.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

In `_Imports.razor` include :

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It seems your solution should work but it doesnt.  The `_counterDiv` is `null` and I dont know how to init it. Anyway +1